# Whatever vs Whichever

Tags: word-usage, usage

My friend had written:

> Send me **whichever** observations you have.

Shouldn't it have been:

> Send me **whatever** observation you have.

P.S. Observations: Readings for different experiments.

Thank you:)

Answer (score 2):

**whichever** uses to emphasize a lack of restriction in selecting one of a definite set of alternatives. 
while 
**whatever** uses to emphasize a lack of restriction in referring to anything or amount, no matter what.